# File path is not working inside JAR file

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I am developing one Java Swing application, I have one file(eg **key.text**) which contains the key for decryption, decryption is performed using third party library, What I am doing for decryption is passing the key.txt to library method.

Eclipse workspace structure

```
src
  com.org.controller
  com.org.beans
  key.txt
```

I have tried passing bin path in following way,

```
String keyFilePath = "bin/key.txt";
aesEncrypt.setSecretKey(keyFilePath); // passing path to library method
```

Code snippet is working smoothly when I am running in eclipse, but when I am packaging it in a jar it is not working.

I tried doing using `getResource()` in following manner but this too is not working.

```
URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/key.txt");
File file = new File(url.toURI());
String keyFilePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
aesEncrypt.setSecretKey(new File(keyFilePath).getAbsolutePath()); // passing path to library method
```

So my question is, How can I pass the resource path which is residing in builded jar?

Comment: bin folder does not exist in jar file

Comment: Usually you should use a `ClassLoader` (e.g. `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()`) for retrieving such resources: `loader.getResource("key.txt")`. This `getResource` method returns a `URL`, so the next step should be to find out whether your library provides a method that takes such a URL.

Comment: What is the type of `aesEncrypt`?  Does it have any methods which accept a URL or InputStream instead of a File?  A .jar file is actually a zip file with a few Java-specific entries in it.  key.txt is an entry in a zip file, not a separate file, so you can *never* use java.io.File to read it.

Comment: @VGR it needs String path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it appears the API you’re calling requires a file name, you’ll need to copy your resource, which is a zip entry and not an actual file, to an actual file:

```
Path file = Files.createTempFile(null, ".txt");
try (InputStream stream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/key.txt")) {
    Files.copy(stream, file, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}

aesEncrypt.setSecretKey(file.toString());
```

Comment: what do you mean by zip entry?

Comment: A zip file is a single file that acts as an archive.  Every member of a zip archive is a zip entry.  As I said in a comment above, a .jar file is actually a zip file with a different extension.

Comment: Okay. But what if my file extension is no txt, do I have to change extension provided in createTempFile() ?

Comment: You can use any extension you want.  You can also pass `null` for the extension to let the system choose a name (since the actual name doesn’t really matter for the purpose of what you’re doing).

Comment: The file has to be created somewhere.  A temp file is guaranteed to be writable.  Any other heuristically chosen directory might or might not be writable.  Plus, the system’s temp directory is easier to clean up than most other locations.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you want, but you could create a folder called bin in the same folder as your jar. Then  put the key.txt file in there.